# How to create a String variable and use batch

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a variable in a batch file and I want to assign a path of a text file to to this variable. After that, I want to use this variable to copy that file. How can I do this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general idea is this:

```
SET filename=c:\path\to\file.txt
COPY "%filename%" c:\destination
```

Note the quotes around `%filename%`: they are necessary to make the command work if the path or file name contains spaces.

Comment: I want to ask a question too,

I have two variables:

SET source=C:\Temp\*.* and
SET targetMove=d:\moveTemp\

I want to move source directory to target directory by using this line:

move /-y "%source%" "%targetMove%"

but it does not work.

How can I do this process?

Thank you,

Comment: @aprogrammer: If it does not work then you are passing the wrong parameters to `move`.